# Is it safe to use XMLInputFactory with system-default implementation?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

In our project we use javax.xml.stream package for XML parsing. I have looked into its documentation and found out how the XMLInputFactory instance is created ([Link here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#newFactory--)). It says that I can provide XMLInputFactory implementation using javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory system property. There are also some other points in the lookup procedure but in the end it takes "the system-default implementation". My questions are: what is that "system-default implementation"? Does it differ between different systems? E.g., if I run our application on one computer and then on another, different implementations might be provided? What is the reason of using other implementations?

Thank you in advance for every answer!

Comment: The main difference  you're likely to experience with different implementations is different bugs and performance.

Comment: @biziclop so what do you suggest? using system-default?